# Unable to resolve the name 'handels.EditField'

Tags: matlab, resize, image-resizing

this Function told me
Unable to resolve the name 'handels.EditField'.
i am using Matlab App Designer

```
            w = str2double(get(handels.EditField,"string"));
            h = str2double(get(handels.EditField2,"string"));
            app.m3= imresize(app.m1, [w h]);
            cla(app.UIAxes_2);
            imshow(app.m3,'Parent',app.UIAxes_2);
```

i cant find where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
h = str2num(app.EditField.Value);
w = str2num(app.EditField2.Value);
```

That's the error because the image resizer function takes `Int` not `Double`.